# How to build 3 separate gradle project using composite build

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have 3 projects - A, B and C. They share the same core module **shared_core**. Every one of that project can be build using its **gradlew build** command. But I would like that shared_core will be built only once not thrice, since it is waste of time. I was told that I can use multi project build or composite build for that.

Right now I am trying to create composite build of those 3 but I am struggling.

Can someone show me the example of how my build.gradle and settings.gradle should look like for this task ?

I am really new to gradle so thank you for any help.

Comment: Are A, B, C, and shared_core  separate projects that live in separate repositories, or do they all live in the same repository?

Comment: @0xadecimal They live in same repository I guess but I am not sure how to find it out. I have a project in intelij which contains 3 subproject and all of them are standalone app which share some of my modules like shared_core.

Comment: @0xadecimal if you mean git repositories that the answer is yes.

Comment: ok thanks, so I assume your structure is something like: `project/A,
project/B,
project/C,
project/shared_core`

Comment: @0xadecimal Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The [gradle guide to creating multi project builds](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/) is an excellent starting point in understanding this topic - I suggest you work through in.  In the short-term here's an answer to your question based on your feedback in the comments:

Assuming your project structure is something like

```
testproject/A
testproject/B
testproject/C
testproject/shared_modules
```

you need to:

1. Add `testproject/settings.gradle` with the following entry: `include 'A', 'B', 'C', 'shared_core'`
2. The `build.gradle` files in `A, B, C` should contain the following dependency definition:

   `dependency compile project(':shared_core')`

As a concrete example, here is the configuration for a simple dummy gradle multimodule project that has the structure outlined above:

**testproject/settings.gradle:**

```
rootProject.name = 'testproject'
include 'A', 'B', 'C', 'shared_core'
```

**testproject/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'uk.co.so.answers'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

**testproject/{A,B,C}/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'uk.co.so.answers'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':shared_core')
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

**testproject/shared_core/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'uk.co.so.answers'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Now, to build all projects, run from the project root:

```
   ./gradlew clean build
```

Comment: I have already tried that solution but my projects A, B and C have really complicated settings.gradle and build.gradle. It would take me a long time to rewrite. That is why I was trying to do similar thing with composite build (but I am not sure if it is possible and if so - how).